# Adobe AIR Facebook login setup

Tags: facebook, air, adobe

I need to implement facebook login in Adobe AIR app for Desktop/Mobile.
I saw some docs on the code required for this.
My concern is, which platform should be selected in facebook apps console. Is it web ? Then what should be the web urls & where to place them ?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are building a mobile app, then you might want to select Android or iOS depending on the platform. If you are building the same app for both platforms then select any one of those and later under `settings` of your app dashboard you can click on `Add Platform` and add the other one. If your app has a canvas presence then you can add that as well later on. Regardless of what you pick initially, you can always add/edit platforms on your app dashboard.